# Verify database is indexed by Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch to index and search my db...

1. How can I verify that the database is indexed?
2. If I use the following command:

   curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=whatever'

the results are:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

How should these results be interpreted?

Comment: You queried for the word whatever and didn't find anything. Remove the query and see the total hits returned to see how many documents are available in the index in total.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of indices present in your database using the command. You can see if your index is present in the list. That shows that index has been created.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
```

To check if there are any entries present in your Index. You can get the list of all the documents using this command.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_search?v&pretty'
```

In the question that you posted. 
"_shards" {
    "total" : gives how many entries are present in your index (6 here)
  }
"hits" : {
    "total" : gives you the entries that matched your search with keyword whatever (0 here)
}

Answer (score 0):

1. To check if your db has been indexed, you can try the command:

   `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases'?pretty=true`
   where you can see the list of indices and check if yours has been indexed.
2. The command you used basically searches for the keyword "whatever" in all of the indices. 
   But it was not able to find anything. Hence you get the following output:
   The search was successful (depicted by "took":4, "timed_out":false, "_shards":"total":6, "successful":6, "failed":0}) but it did not find anything (depicted by "hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]})